# REGEX : accept only alphanumeric characters and spaces except the spaces at the begining or ending of expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to implement regular expression that accept only alphanumeric characters and spaces except the spaces at the begining or ending of expression.

```
'   aaaa978aa' ===> fail
'aaaaaa      ' ===> fail
'aaaaaaaaAAAa' ===> match
'aaaaaaa  aaa' ===> match
'68776  67576' ===> match
'aAAAa756Gaaa' ===> match
```

Comment: I believe simply asking for a pattern is off-topic. In fact, I don't see any question asked here. Please see [ask] a question with a [mcve] including your own attempt. Kindly note: [How much research effort is expected on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write the regex as the following in case insensitive mode:

```
^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9 ]*[a-z0-9])?$
```

This requires a leading alphanumeric character, along with optional alphas or spaces in the middle, ending also with an alphanumeric character, at least for the case where the length be 2 or more characters.

Sample code:

```js
var inputs = ["   aaaa978aa", "aaaaaa      ", "aaaaaaaaAAAa", "aaaaaaa  aaa", "68776  67576", "aAAAa756Gaaa"];
inputs.forEach(x => console.log(x + (/^[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9 ]*[a-z0-9])?$/i.test(x) ? " : match" : " : fail")));
```

Comment: Also accept expression of one letter or  one number

Comment: @barsawi13 ... my pattern accepts a single letter or number

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^\w+(?:[ \t]+)?\w+$
```

`^` : Asserts position at start of a line

`\w+` : Matches any word character (equivalent to [a-zA-Z0-9_]), between one and unlimited times.

`(?:[ \t]+)?` : Non capturing group, matches the spaces and tab, `?` ensures to match the previous token between 0 and 1 time.

`$`:  Asserts position at end of a line

https://regex101.com/r/sMcYuq/1